# Apt not working after Ubuntu 15.10 Upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade

I did a whole system update and then a distribution upgrade from 14.04 to 15.10. After install I ran apt-get update and started to see some errors. Tried to troubleshoot the dependency issues by hand but I have had little success. Now any apt-get command throws this error.

```
apt-get -f install
apt-get: error while loading shared libraries: libapt-pkg.so.4.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Tried installing the latest libapt package from the wily repo with no luck. (http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/libs/libapt-pkg4.16)

Apt is also calling the 4.12 package which is not on my system. (from strace)

```
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/libapt-pkg.so.4.12", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the highly unlikely event you haven't done so, shut down - NOT simply reboot your computer.

Next, again assuming that you haven't done so:
sudo apt-get autoclean  && sudo apt-get autoremove

Then:
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

Even though you've just upgraded your computer, some of the older config files occassionally still linger around.

Comment: Apt wont run, even after a full shutdown.